# MDS Excel add-in multiple entities in one xls file

Tags: excel, master-data-services, master-data-management

Hi
We have a couple of issues that might be bugs. At least we cannot find any fixes or help on the web.
We have an Excel sheet with a sheet per Entity. All data comes from the same MDS.

[Screenshot of MDS spreadheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE80s.jpg)

### First problem

When we close the spreadsheet and open it again. We connect to MDS again but it is like some of the tabs/sheets does not connect again. The refresh button and publish button is greyed out (see screenshot - I have scrolled away from all the sensitive data). Any tips to fix this would be great!

### Second problem

When above fails we would try to refresh the data fully from the MDS Explorer in Excel. However then it renames the sheet-tab and adds a number "1" at the end? (See Account 1 in screenshot) Is there any way to control this as renaming screws up the sheet for us?

### Third Problem

This is harder to explain and it is a periodical problem - I cant find any way to really trigger it. So I just hope someone have seen this as well and found a fix for it. 
What happens is, while scrolling in one of the Entity sheets suddenly the first two lines which normally is split and freezed suddenly starts scrolling with data from the same sheet? So if you see the screenshot and imagine the 1-2 suddenly shows row 1050-1051 and scrolls as well with the normal rows.

Hard facts about the systems:

```html
<pre>
DatabaseSchemaVersion 
13.1.0.3 

SQLServerVersion 
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU5) (KB4040714) - 13.0.4451.0 (X64) 
        Sep  5 2017 16:12:34 
        Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 
        Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor) 

ProductVersion 
13.1.0.3 

CompatibilityLevel 
110 

OSVersion 
Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard 

Excel Version 
16.0.4705.1000 

Excel Add-in Version 
13.0.5150.0 
</pre>
```

So please any help, pointing in the right direction, or explanation will be received on my knees kissing your hands :)

Comment: For general Excel questions, including those dealing with built in Excel features, functions, and formulas, Super User is absolutely the correct site. [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155487/if-i-had-a-question-with-excel-which-site-would-i-use)

Comment: This was the only place I could find with master data services - And I would think people with master data services experience had more experience with this than random excel people?

Comment: Probably yes, since there is no programming involved here.